# How to make an view controller, which displays only when app opens first time?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I use Xcode 6.4
I want to make an viewController which displays a settings and which opens  only when the app launch at first time, or when a setting contains nil. What can i do, to do such thing?

Comment: add user default and check that condition both are equal open the particular page else open the another viewcontroller

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just set a flag to NSUserDefaults...

```
if (!NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("firstTimeKey")) {
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "firstTimeKey")
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
    showViewController()
}
```

showViewController() is where you call your ViewController that should be showed once...

Comment: @Neo Where should I use this code? In viewController class?

Comment: Well wherever you want mate :-) The "easiest / common" way would be if you just paste it into the viewDidAppear method of your view controller class... It could not be run at viewDidLoad, or viewWillAppear, because its to early in VC Lifecycle and will get an error in Xcode...

Comment: @Neo excuse me, I am a deep beginner:(. I spent a lot of time with this code, but I still don't understand a few things: 1. First of all I paste this code in viewDidAppear(animated:Bool) of class firstViewController. What would I do next? Do I need to make firstView an initial view controller?

Comment: @hello_max no problem, we all started some day... :-) I have created you a Xcode Project and pushed it to github... you can download it from there and check out whats going on... its completely commented https://github.com/DennisWeidmann/OpenVCOnce

Answer (score 3):

I typically solve this problem by creating a `CoreData` Entity called `AppConfig` and I give it any important properties to do with Application state, *time open, user settings* ect...

Upon App Launch if the `CoreData` entity does not exist, than I create it, and know that its the first launch and that I should display the "FirstLaunch" or "Help" `ViewController`.

Here is an example of what I'd do:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var fetch = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "AppConfig")
    var appConfigs = managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(fetch, error: error) as! [AppConfig]
    if let appConfig = appConfigs.first{
       //App has already launched before
    }else{
       //Create a new AppConfig Object and save it in CoreData
       //Present your FirstLaunch Controller
    }
    return nil
}
```

*In the above code I'm assuming you know the basic concepts of CoreData, and presenting ViewControllers. Both are relatively basic concepts so I'll omit them for now, but if someone does need help with them I can provide more info.*